# Trying to check lines are between 2 points that exist, Prolog

Tags: prolog, line, point

I am trying to check whether lines are actually between 2 points that exist in the rule set. For example in the code below,

```
point(a).
point(z).

line(l,k).
line(k,l).
line(k,a).
line(a,z).
```

`line(a,z).` is a real line because `a` and `z` are both points in the rule set but `line(l,k).` isn't a real line because `l` and `k` aren't real points in the rule set.

I am new to Prolog and would just like some pointers for how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write:

```
real_line(X,Y):-line(X,Y),point(X),point(Y).
```

The `,` in Prolog means logical **"and"** so the above predicate `real_line/2` succeeds when for X,Y holds: `line(X,Y)` and `X` is a point and `Y` is a point.

Some examples:

```
?- real_line(a,z).
true.

?- real_line(a,k).
false.

?- real_line(l,k).
false.

?- real_line(X,Y).
X = a,
Y = z.

?- real_line(X,z).
X = a.

?- real_line(a,Y).
Y = z.
```

---

### UPDATE

Based on your comments to find all incorrect lines you could use:

```
findall(line(X,Y),(line(X,Y), \+ real_line(X,Y)),L).
```

Example:

```
?- findall(line(X,Y),(line(X,Y), \+ real_line(X,Y)),L).
L = [line(l, k), line(k, l), line(k, a)].
```

**OR** with a fail-driven loop:

```
write_incorrect_lines:-
            line(X,Y),
            \+real_line(X,Y),
            write(line(X,Y)),
            nl,
            fail;
            true.
```

Example:

```
?- write_incorrect_lines.
line(l,k)
line(k,l)
line(k,a)
true.
```

Comment: So how would I go about checking all the lines were correct? Would I have to load them into a list in a function?

Comment: You mean that you need all the lines that are connect or just check if all lines are correct??

Comment: I would like to search through the file and all the lines that are incorrect write to the console